# Mysqld.exe memory usage

Tags: mysql

I am using **mysql 5.6.14**, For a long time i got large memory usage by mysqld.exe, i was trying many different solutions and my.ini settings to fix this up but didn't succeed, This is my config file([my.ini](http://pastebin.com/0rZEaPw2)), When i start mysqld via command line(mysqld --console) this is the output:

```
2013-11-14 18:30:36 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --ex
plicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1796484 and 1796484 in ibdata files
 do not match the log sequence number 1796504 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-11-14 18:30:36 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.14 started; log sequence number 1796504
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-11-14 18:30:37 4440 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-11-14 18:30:38 4440 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-11-14 18:30:38 4440 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.14'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Usually i am using **net start mysql** to start mysql server but so you may notice some problem i used **mysqld --console**.

As you can see this is the capture from my resource monitor:

[image]

If anyone know how to solve/reduce memory usage I will be very thankful.

---

**Edit:**
Thank you for your answer, Without changing anything at my.ini this is the value i get for `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'join_buffer_size';`:

```
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| join_buffer_size | 262144 |
+------------------+--------+
```

If i understand you i should set all my my.ini settings up to 4mb, So After i set:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 4M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
```

This is the new memory usage:

[image]

About `SHOW ENGINE PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA STATUS;` i was amazed by the numbers: http://pastebin.com/J6GfV591

About `per-connection memory`, I am using a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for mysql connections so after i search for **pre-connection memory** i am not sure if it is **pre-query memory** or **pre-connection memory**, If its **pre-query memory** so my singleton pattern is not related to the subject, So if you can some me where do i set the pre-connection memory because **i don't know if it is mysql variable or my.ini directive**.

Comment: There's nothing particularly interesting in your startup logs other than the fact that *before* this, there appears to have been a crash or otherwise non-graceful shutdown.  Your resource monitor screen shot only shows 550MB of memory allocated.  How much is too much, and how long does it take to rise to that level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that your server seems to have recovered from a crash, according to the init log. Something strange may have happened there related to your problems (a crash, a non-clean stop, a memory leak, etc.)

There are several reasons why MySQL 5.6 may be consuming a lot of memory (specially compared to 5.5).

You have a 128Mb buffer pool (default), that may consume around 150 MB of memory having into account the extra buffers. Aside from other global buffers, you have to add the per-connection memory. You have a huge join_buffer_size on your configuration (128M), but it is commented. Make sure that it is not set to that value by executing:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'join_buffer_size';
```

Anything bigger that 4MB is normally not recommended.

The first one I would check, however, -which several people have reported memory problems with- is the performance_schema, a new feature that has been enabled by default in 5.6. You can check its memory consumption by doing:

```
SHOW ENGINE PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA STATUS;
```

For more information, we would need the runtime statistics of the server, namely:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

---

## Edit to your edit

**Do not set the Buffer Pool to 4 MB!** That is a global value, and the most important cache buffer if you are using InnoDB.  That is too little even for an embedded system. The 4Mb was just for the join_buffer_size. If you don't know what to put there, and as you seem to be aiming for low memory usage, set it to something around the 50-80% of the total memory you aim to consume.

Your performance_schema consumption is certainly worrying. Set `performance_schema = off` on your configuration and restart MySQL Server.

Regarding per-connection-memory: simply you must know that there are some variables that reserve memory per action or per session. join_buffer_size, sort_buffer_size, etc. are session variables; innodb_buffer_pool_size is global to the server and is only reserved once. If you are using a single connection to the server, you may not have to worry too much. But please share the complete output of the previous commands, and your hardware specs/memory usage aims.

Comment: I finish editing my question if you can please check it, Thank you.

Comment: Jynus, Thank you so much now i can adjust the memory usage,  I got this problem for a long time, Just last question i got if you may please answer, What is the difference between "per action/per session", Thanks again and have a nice day.

Comment: According to MySQL, there are only 2 kinds of variables: global or session.  You can set both independently, but session variables only will effect until the connection drops off. There are certain variables that only can be set globally (like innodb_buffer_pool_size) and many can be set both globally and per session:
`mysql> SET SESSION join_buffer_size = 5M;` (the default, the change will be lost after you close connection)
`mysql> SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = 5M;` (it will affect all new sessions)
The importance here is how this affect the server:
Many values are just limits (maximums)...

Comment: ... while others are allocated entirely per session (for every connection). While others, are allocated every time they are needed (even several times per connection): Have a look at the `join_buffer_size`, that [is allocated once per join and per connection](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/07/05/how-is-join_buffer_size-allocated/). Hope this helps.

Comment: @jynus THANK YOU SO MUCH I just added `performance_schema = off` under `[mysql]` in the `my.ini` file and **mysql.exe** switched from 550MB+ to only 25MB of ram!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I'm using XAMPP v3.2.1 and didn't have this problem with the previous version of XAMPP. Very easy fix, in the XAMPP Control Panel simply click __"Config > my.ini"__ next to MySQL.

Comment: @admin, I got it working under [mysqld] (and not [mysql]) as per barbolo's answer. Also running XAMPP 3.2.1. Glad my 500MB on MYSQL is now a thing of the past!

Answer (score 1):

Locate you mysql configuration file (usally, my.ini or my.cnf) and add this:

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = off
```

Answer (score 1):

If the server was installed as a "Development Machine", the problem is may be due to `table_definition_cache=1400` configured by the installer in my.ini. The min/default value is 400.

[Troubleshooting High Memory Usage with MySQL on Windows](http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/pfs_table_share-row_size/)