# Couldn't start MySQL

Tags: mysql

I looked in the other threads, but this did not resolve my problem. I am trying to start MySQL, but I am getting error as below

```
D:\>cd mysql\mysql5.6.15\program\bin\mysqld --console
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\>cd mysql\mysql5.6.15\program\bin

D:\MySQL\mysql5.6.15\program\bin>mysqld --console
2014-01-18 14:12:01 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_def
aults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Binlog end
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

How I can resolve the issue ?

Comment: Might this link addressed your issue http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/mysqld-exe-memory-usage

Comment: Again: `2014-01-18 14:12:01 4488 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode` - please fix that.

Comment: @Mat.Thank you very much Mat, I won't post on two different forums anymore. I don't know what .\ibdata is and what to do about it. I will google for it. I hope I get some answers.

Comment: ibdata is innodb's master data file. It will hold all data constructs including the data dictionary if innodb_file_per_table is not used. If innodb_file_per_table  = 1 then ibdata still exists for data dictionary and undo segments. There's plenty of info on dev.mysql.com documentation regarding the file. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue I have encountered recently. With MySQL stopped, move the ib_logfile* from the data directory (perhaps to /tmp to be safe). Then start mysql and watch the log for progress.

I didn't check for bugs yet but I'd wager something has been logged.

Let us know how you get on.